# Google Dataflow Java SDK raises an exception during data migration

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I've got a lot of data in BigQuery which has to be migrated into Spanner (64 billion rows, about 38 TB)

I'm using Apache Beam SDK to copy data from BigQuery into Spanner.

Here you can see how the Dataflow Console looks like:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRP7F.png (an error occurred on the last stage "Write mutations to Cloud Spanner")
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR0ZR.png (if I expand it I can see that error occurred at 3 stages: "Group by partition", "Batch mutations together", "Write mutations to Spanner")

If I go to error logs I can see:

3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYNO5.png (there were the same errors happen for 7 times and then it crashed saying that the worker lost contact with the service)

What is the reason of this crash? Where can I find an explanation for this? Is there any way to fix this?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Which machine type are you using? Can you try running the job with bigger instance like [high-memory machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#highmem)? You can specify the machine type in your [PipelineOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options) object.